# How to store an image file in bash variable?

Tags: bash, cat, images, binary, variable

After I use the following command,

```
pngString="$(cat example.png)"    
echo -n "$pngString" > tmp.png
```

I can't open the tmp.png as a PNG file. Maybe some information is lost when I use `$pngString` to store the image file.

So the question is: How can I store the complete image information using a variable in bash script?

Comment: The cat command works fine (to store the image data in the variable). Just remove the double quotes. The question is what you want to do with this data after saving them in the variable?

Comment: `cat` and `echo` and all its ilk are at heart **text** utilities. Letting them loose unsuspectingly on binary files will have unpredictable results. That's why things like `base64` were invented.

Comment: Why do you want to have it as a variable? Shell variables are typically intended to store small amount of text, not large amounts of binary data. None of the usual shell can cope with binary data in variables (they choke on null bytes) except zsh.

Comment: Why not just `cat example.png > tmp.png` or better yet, `cp example.png tmp.png`?

Comment: @Shadur, `cat` isn't really a text utility.  It's the command substitution (which strips trailing newlines), the variable assignment (which can't contain null bytes) and the `echo` command (which may interpret backslash sequences) which will mangle the binary, not `cat`.  But I agree with your overall point.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are right in that `echo` & company don't seem to handle binary that well. I suspect that the null characters break the stream all too early.

You can convert picture information in some ASCII based format. For instance, this is with `base64`:

```
$ pic=`base64 pic.jpeg`
$ echo $pic | base64 --decode > pic2.jpeg
$ diff pic*
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: In my bash system I had to enclose the variable in quotes, probably because base64 can contain white space:  `echo "$pic" | base64 --decode > pic2.jpeg`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that null bytes cannot be passed through command line arguments as they are internally used as argument terminators. All other bytes seem to be fine. So a somewhat more space-efficient (typically) alternative to using `base64` would be to escape the null bytes and then use `printf` to convert the data to original form:

```
pngString="$(sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/%/%%/g;s/\x00/\\x00/g' <example.png)"
printf "$pngString" >tmp.png
```

The `\` and `%` characters are special to `printf` so they need to be escaped too.

Also note that if the input data ends with a newline, it will get stripped by command substitution. That should not be an issue specifically for PNGs as the last byte in a valid PNG should be 0x82, the least significant byte in the empty `IEND` chunk's CRC sum.

Comment: If you want even more backslashes, use:

    `sed s/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/g\;s/%/%%/g\;s/\\x00/\\\\x00/g`